# rails access view name inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a partial that I am using in different pages. I want to conditionally hide a certain div inside the partial based on the view that is rendering it.

I was thinking about creating a page specific javascript file that would look up the div and and hide it.

But, if there was a way to retrieve the view name / page name inside the partial it would be central to the partial and would not necessitate loading the same javascript file in multiple pages.

Does anybody know a way to do this inside a partial

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While @wahaj's answer would work, if you want to do what you need in a central location, you could check the `controller_name` and `action_name` variables in the partial to determine the view you're in (e.g. `controller_name == "services"` and `action_name == "show"` would let you know you're in the Show view for the Service controller)

Comment: params[:controller] or params[:action] are not recommended, instead use 'controller_name','action_name'

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Didn't even know that existed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You'd better edit your original answer to reflect this then, or people may do what you said originally.

Comment: @Naveed can elaborate on why it's not recommended?

Comment: @adamwong246 well we `params` is a hash and we can change its values( params[:controller]='blakh') yep why would anyone change values for :controller, :action but still humans are errors pron. `controller_name` is safe to use.

Comment: Doesn't always work, due to `rails`' developers custom of rendering in non-`GET` requests, like in `devise`'s `passwords/update` action.

Comment: `action_name` is not exactly the same as the view name. Eg, in a `create` action, if something is invalid, you might `render :new`.

Answer (score 6):

you can get the name of the currently-rendering partial from within a Helper method with the following :

```
controller.view_context.view_renderer.instance_variable_get('@_partial_renderer').instance_values['path']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could send the style parameter as a local variable to the partial, varying the parameter depending on where you're calling from. Something like:

```
render :partial => 'xyz', :locals => {:style => 'display:none or display:block'}
```

and in the partial you could do:

```
<div style=<%=style%>></div>
```

Comment: or perhaps a local var 'hide_div'.  A nicety with partials is the defined? method, which means the variable would not be required on all calls to render the partial.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution , inside your partial check if you need to show partial or not

_partial_name.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :div, :style=> "display : #{show_div? ? 'block' : 'none'}" do%>
  html...or other stuff
 <%end%>
```

and then in application helper

app/helper/application_helper.rb

```
def show_div? #you can set name of your div like 'show_sidebar_div?'
  #decide either show this div or not
 action_name == 'show'
end
```