# How can I check which page has sent the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to be sure that the data I receive came from a specific page (it's for a navigator game).

I would prefer a solution using RoR but if we can do it with JS it's ok =)

Comment: You can find the name of the view.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846484/rails-access-view-name-inside-partial

Comment: Or if you mean the page that referred you to the current page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819721/how-to-get-request-referrer-path

Comment: Its super easy to fake a referrer header so don't trust it to be actually reliable if you think someone may tamper with data.

Comment: It's just a precaution I would regret to not take

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In your controller**, you have access to the `request` variable (type of `ActionDispatch::Request`) which represents the actual request received by your server:

```
def index
  puts request.inspect # see in your server's console the output
  # ...
end
```

With this variable, you can access to the `referer`, which returns the path (as String) of the last page seen, or `nil` if you came from another domain (or blank page).

---

**To check which page sent your form**, you could use:

```
def my_controller_action
  if request.referer.present? && request.referer.include?('/string/to/check/')
    # yay!
  else
    # well, the request is not coming from there
  end
end
```

---

You could also set it as a `before_filter` in your controller in order to check "quietly" the requests and not in each controller's action.